# Amazon のサイトはどの言語で作られていますか？

Tags: プログラミング言語

Amazon のような通販サイト、総合モールを作りたいです。
色々な会社の商品を扱う通販モールサイトを作りたいです。
Amazon はプログラミング言語は何を使って作られていますか？

Amazon に使われてるようなソフトの開発などもしたいですが、何の言語から勉強したらいいか分かりません。
プログラミングは初心者であり、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: こんな記事があるようです。[Amazonが内部で使っているプログラミング言語は何ですか？](https://jp.quora.com/Amazon%E3%81%8C%E5%86%85%E9%83%A8%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)

Comment: ありがとうございます。JavaとJavascriptはどちらも使われていますか？どちらを勉強したらいいか分からなく、分かりましたら教えてください。

Comment: 紹介した記事を見る限り、最初にJavaは使われていると書かれており、JavaScriptは書かれていませんがクライアント(ブラウザ)側での処理に必須でしょう。サーバーサイドならJavaなり他の良さそうな言語を、クライアントサイドならJavaScript系の何かを、それぞれ重点にしてみれば良いと思われます。

Comment: クライアント、サーバーの言葉を初めて調べました。JavaとJavaScriptどちらも処理に必要だということですね？どちらも勉強しようと思います。初心者ですみません。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 5):

Amazon は巨人です。現在出ている[求人情報](https://www.amazon.jobs/jp)をざっと見るだけでも、

> C、C++、Scala、Java、Python、Ruby、Go、C#

と多肢に渡っています。他にも使っている言語が有るのは確実です。基盤のアーキテクチャも尋常ならざる物で、AWS として販売されています。プログラミング初心者が参考にするには厳しい相手かと思います。利用者として AWS を使うことで、ある意味 Amazon と同じ技術構成にはなるかもしれませんが。

巨人の真似をするのでは無く、もうすこし気軽に始められる物を選ぶのが良いでしょう。

Webサービスを作るにあたり、ライブラリやフレームワークが揃っていて、初心者向けの書籍などが期待できる言語としては、以下が有ります。（主観を排してリストアップしたつもりです。順序に意味は有りません）

- Ruby
- Python
- JavaScript (Node.js)
- PHP
- Java

Comment: ありがとうございます。すごく参考になりました！頑張って基礎から勉強してみます。

Comment: 求人情報から分析する手法勉強になります。

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub](https://github.com/amzn)で公開されているAmazon製プログラムでは、Python/Java/Swift/JavaScript/PHPなどが使われています。
また[Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19495225)によるとJava/C++/Python/Ruby/Go/Perl/Scala/Rustなどが使われているそうです。

ですが他の回答にもあるように、Amazonは多数のユーザーからの無数の商品への大量のアクセスを安定的に捌くために大規模なシステムの上になりなっているので、個人で真似するのには向きません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考になりました。基礎を勉強してみます。

Answer (score 0):

chromeでの確認方法になりますが、適当なアマゾンのページを開いて右クリック。
「ページのソースを表示」するとhtml構文・Javascript構文が確認できます。

このことから最低限度html + css + javasriptは確定で含まれております。

次に、F12キーを押して開発者モードを表示し、おそらく開発者モード上部にあるだろう「ソース」をクリックすると、フォルダ・ファイル形式でそのページで読み込んでいる外部ファイル群が表示されます。ファイルの末尾が.jpegなどのものは画像なので無視するとして、.jsファイルが含まれる事からも外部インポートのJavascriptファイルも使用していることがわかります。

また、一般的な話としてこのようなサイト構成の場合、phpを使用していると考えるのが妥当ですが、phpの記述に関しては原則、外部からソースコードの表示やダウンロードを行った場合において強制的に非表示になり存在が秘匿されます。これは個人情報のブロックを分解してページ内にちりばめたりする時にセキュリティ的に露呈してはいけない部分をphpで書くのが一般的なためです。

以上のことから自力でガリガリ書く上では、少なくとも書式としてhtml + css + Javascript + phpの勉強は必要となるでしょう。

また、サイト自体を設計するだけであればこれらの勉強で済みますが、実際に個人情報などのデータを個別管理するような部分に関してはデータベース（DB）をどのように使うのか？

や

大量のトラフィック（ユーザがアクセスしてきた際の通信の量）をどのように捌くのかというネットワーク周り、サーバー設計周りと無尽蔵に派生していってしまいます。

特にアマゾン・楽天・ヤフーなどの大手レベルになってくると大の大人が束になって年単位でこれらすべての仕様・要件を設計しながら開発していきます。

初歩的な機能の開発→影響のある部分を後で修正→追加でできた機能を実装→影響のある部分を修正と個人で行いながらこの分量を捌くのは無理があります。

まずはざっと簡単に、ページ構造の構築（html）・装飾（css）を行い、phpの類系で個人アカウントの設営にまつわる勉強・購入者アカウント/販売者アカウント/管理者アカウントの開設の勉強をして組込・商品を出品する構造や購入する構造・・・・etcと「ざっと簡単に」と簡易化しても数秒で思いつくだけでこれくらいの分量があります。

さらにセキュリティ対策という地獄もございます。（漏洩したら…損★害★賠★償という）

個人で作成するにはあまりにも膨れ上がりすぎているので十分な心の余裕を持って挑戦してください。

また、現在メルカリやミンネなどの販売サイトを開設したい場合、完成済みの基礎フレームに画像や色などのレイアウト修正のみを行う小規模な開発方法が出回ってます。
ワードプレスなどで完成済みの基礎フレームをサイト規模と比較したら格安で販売していたりします。そちらで購入したものに肉付けするなどの改修を行う方法が安価となってきています。

詳しくは「通販サイト作成」とかでネットで見つかると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます♪すごく参考になりました。検索の仕方も分からず困っていました。本当にありがとうございます！